# Exporting MS Dynamics CRM Accounts Entity with Notes

Tags: dynamics-crm, export-to-excel, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

We are running an On-Premise version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM. Our extact version is:

Microsoft Dynamics® CRM 2013 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
(6.1.4.145) 
(DB 6.1.4.145)

I would like to export the Accounts and Contacts entities with the associated NOTES fields. But under the advanced find tool, I do not see that field as an available option when trying to export.

How can I accomplish this?

My goal is to export the required entities to an Excel Spreadsheet for import into another database system.

Comment: When you mean Notes - is that out of Box Notes or your custom fields?

Comment: The out of box Notes section. Not a custom field.

Comment: If you are using on-premise, it may be easier for you to write a sql query instead of using the (very limited) advanced find tool.

Answer (score 2):

Notes can be exported from Adv.Find separately like Accounts & Contacts. (Associated records wont export from Parent entity export). You have to filter the regarding entity only for Account/Contact to filter out other entity Notes.

At the end you will have 3 datasets (excel) with Accounts, Contacts, Notes which you can use it for import in destination. If you want the GUIDs of CRM records, make sure to check the checkbox for re-import - this will give hidden Id columns in exported excel - you can map for relationship.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to export and I see the GUID's (Collumn A in the the export). But for the Notes export, each note has a unique GUID, so how can I map that to the corresponding account entity?

Comment: Unique GUID is primary key of that record (annotationid, accountid). The regardingobjectid (objectid) in notes is mapped to account/contact in association with object type code.

Comment: IMaybe due to my version but I don't see the checkbox for re-import. But interestingly enough when I save a CSV I see those hidden fields you mention. When I save my Notes export as a CSV, here are my columns: (Do Not Modify) Note, (Do Not Modify) Row Checksum, (Do Not Modify) Modified On, Title, Description, File Name, Created By, Created By (Delegate), Created On, File Size (Bytes), Is Document, Modified By, Modified By (Delegate), Modified On, Note, Owner, Record Created On. I'm assuming collumn A is the note's GUID. But I am unable to get the regardingobjectid (objectid) field to show.

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem like the contents of the notes are being exported as well. Do I need to add another grouping to my query?

Comment: The notes themselves will be in the documentbody field of the annotation entity, which you need to relate to their parent entities through regardingobjectid. I would really suggest writing (or having someone else) write a sql query for you. Advanced Find is lacking.

Comment: body contents will be in description..title should have subject line. like Jacob mentioned, SQL query may be powerful in your on-premise scenario. I see regardingobjectid is missing in available columns list from adv find but easily queryable in SQL.